# devise login rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This may be somewhat of a simple question but if i add a column called name to the devise User model and then add :name to attr_accessible in the User model, can i allow a user to login without specifying their name,

so sign up form looks like this

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<p><%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %></p>

<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></p>

<p><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>

<p><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

and the sign in form will look like this

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
<% end -%>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I just want to be able to collect their name upon sign up so i can use it later on in the app, but its not needed for login credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users signing in using email and password by default. You can add so much fields as you want in the registration form. It's will not affect on the sign in behavior.